# Comparing Page.User.Identity.Name to value in sql Table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, authentication

First, I am SO sorry if the answer is out there. I've looked and looked and feel this is such a simple thing that it should be obvious.

I'm wanting to make sure only the person who added an event can modify it. Simple!

I already have a datasource that has event_added_by as a data point. It is populating a FormView.

```
       SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_events] WHERE ([event_ID] = @event_ID)"
```

And I have Page.User.Identity.Name.

How do I compare the two? I can't pull the value from the label in the FormView so I need to find another way.

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string uname = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        string owner = ""// this is where I need to grab the value from dsEvents;

        if (uname != owner)
        {
            //Send them somewhere saying they're not allowed to be here
        }

    }
```

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're already storing the name of who created the event in the table `tbl_events` and with your select all sentence you're bringing back that information also, so why don't compare that? The value returned from your select command specific column directly with your user name?

Comment: I know. It should be simple. How do I do it? Give me the code. I think I'm having tunnel vision and just don't see it. I'm missing something that's so easy, I'm sure.

Comment: Then put the structure of the `tbl_events`